# How to select rows by group with the minimum value and containing NAs in R

Tags: r, dataframe, na

Here is an example:

```
set.seed(123)    
data<-data.frame(X=rep(letters[1:3], each=4),Y=sample(1:12,12),Z=sample(1:100, 12))
data[data==3]<-NA
```

What I am to realize is to select the unique row of `X` with minimum `Y` by ignoring `NA`s:

```
a 4 68
b 1 4
c 2 64
```

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `data.table` package, this is trivial:

```
library(data.table)

d <- data.table(data)
d[, min(Y, na.rm=TRUE), by=X]
```

You can also use `plyr` and its `ddply` function:

```
library(plyr)

ddply(data, .(X), summarise, min(Y, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Or using base R:

```
aggregate(X ~ ., data=data, FUN=min)
```

---

Based on the edits, I would use `data.table` for sure:

```
d[, .SD[which.min(Y)], by=X]
```

However, there are solutions using base R or other packages.

Comment: It works for this case, but actually my data set has 20s columns. I would select the rows with all columns rather than a summary of two. Some suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand.  Please edit your question to reflect your actual... question...

Answer (score 1):

This does not select the rows using an index but returns the values you want...

```
ddply(data, .(X), summarise, min=min(Y, na.rm=T))

  X min
1 a   5
2 b   1
3 c   4
```

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT**: To select the whole rows you may:

```
ddply(data, .(X), function(x) arrange(x, Y)[1, ])

  X Y  Z
1 a 4 68
2 b 1  4
3 c 2 64
```

Or

```
data$index <- 1L:nrow(data)
i <- by(data, data$X, function(x) x$index[which.min(x$Y)] )
data[i, ]

   X Y  Z index
1  a 4 68     1
6  b 1  4     6
10 c 2 64    10
```

Comment: It does work for this case, but I updated my example to be more specific for my goal. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Using subset to for each letter may be this can help

```
data<-data.frame(X=rep(letters[1:3], each=4),Y=sample(1:12,12))
dataA <- subset(data, data$X=="a")
min(dataA$Y, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `data.table` way

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)    
data<-data.frame(X=rep(letters[1:3], each=4),Y=sample(1:12,12),Z=sample(1:100, 12))
data[data==3]<-NA
data <- data.table(data)
data[data[,.I[which.min(Y)], by = "X"][,V1]]
```