# how to select the minimum pvalue and the next closer to the minimum in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Here is an example about what I want:

```
set.seed(123)    
data<-data.frame(X=rep(letters[1:3], each=4),Y=sample(1:12,12),Z=sample(1:100, 12))
setDT(data)
```

What I would like to do is to select the unique row of X with minimum Y and the next closer value to the minimum

Desired output

```
>data
a 4 68
a 5 11
b 1 4
b 10 89
c 2 64
c 3 82
```

The min value is already answer in this post [How to select rows by group with the minimum value and containing NAs in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046425/how-to-select-rows-by-group-with-the-minimum-value-and-containing-nas-in-r)

```
data[, .SD[which.min(Y)], by=X]
```

But how to do it with the minimum and the next closer?

Comment: Assuming your data frame is a data table, what about `data[rank(Y) %in% 1:2 , ]` or, for a regular data frame `data[rank(data$Y) %in% 1:2, ]`?

Comment: thanks @eipi10, I have used `data[, .SD[rank(Y) %in% 1:2] , by=X]`, and it worked. If you answer my question I'll give you the credit :-)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the fact that you were also grouping  by `X`. Feel free to answer the question yourself. There's no problem with answering your own question.

Comment: You deserve it, please write a brief answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the ungrouped case, for a data.table you can do:

```
data[rank(Y) %in% 1:2, ]
```

For the grouped case, you can do:

```
data[ , .SD[rank(Y) %in% 1:2] , by=X]
```

> ```
>    X  Y  Z
> 1: a  4 68
> 2: a  5 11
> 3: b  1  4
> 4: b 10 89
> 5: c  3 82
> 6: c  2 64
> ```

Comment: Shameless plug for my eponym: data.table also has an `frank()` function. Here's the standard reference for the grouped case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16574176/

Comment: @Frank, I didn't realize you pronounced your name "eff-rank".